# Prevent a notification going away from notification bar [Android]

Tags: android, kotlin, android-notifications

First of all, I am sorry if there is a topic on this but I didn't found the exact solution.
The problem is that, I am setting a notification but when I close the app, the notification is removed automatically by the system. You might think it is relevant to **onGoing** attribute but as far as I know it is required user interaction. In my case, notifications disappear by itself.

Here is the code:

```
class NotificationHelper {
private val CHANNEL_ID: String = "Default Channel ID"
private var context: Context
private var notificationManager: NotificationManager
private var notificationBuilder: NotificationCompat.Builder

constructor(context: Context) {
    this.context = context
    this.notificationManager =
        this.context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager

    // NotificationChannel is required on Oreo and newer
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        this.notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(
            NotificationChannel(
                CHANNEL_ID,
                this.context.getString(R.string.channel_name),
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH
            )
        )
    }

    notificationBuilder = NotificationCompat.Builder(this.context, CHANNEL_ID)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_set_notification_black)
        .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
        .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_MESSAGE)
        .setNotificationSilent()
        .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX)
        .setContentIntent(
            PendingIntent.getActivity(
                this.context, 0, Intent(
                    this.context,
                    MainActivity::class.java
                ), 0
            )
        )
}

fun setNotification(notification: Notification) {
    val deleteIntent = Intent(context, BootOrUpdateBroadcastReceiver::class.java)
    deleteIntent.action = GlobalInfo.ACTION_NOTIFICATION_DELETE
    deleteIntent.putExtra(GlobalInfo.NotificationEntry.COLUMN_ID, notification.id)

    val notificationToBeShown: android.app.Notification = this.notificationBuilder
        .setContentTitle(notification.title)
        .setContentText(notification.content)
        .setStyle(NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(notification.content))
        .setAutoCancel(notification.removeByClick)
        .setOngoing(!notification.removeBySwipeAway)
        .setDeleteIntent(
            PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                context,
                0,
                deleteIntent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT
            )
        )
        .build()

    with(NotificationManagerCompat.from(this.context)) {
        // notificationId is a unique int for each notification that you must define
        notify(notification.id, notificationToBeShown)
    }

}

fun clearNotification(notificationId: Int) {
    this.notificationManager.cancel(notificationId)
}

fun clearAllNotifications() {
    this.notificationManager.cancelAll()
}

}
```

Also, I thought to use a sticky service but it doesn't make sense to me. Services are also being destroyed as the application is closed. There should be another way.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: `You might think it is relevant to onGoing attribute but as far as I know it is required user interaction` Can you explain this? An ongoing notification will be dismissed when an app is closed and no, a [foreground service](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/foreground-services) is not destroyed when the app is closed

Comment: I mean I am not trying to dismiss the notification as user by swiping away or clicking it. It is done by the android device as I close the application. So, it's not relevant to onGoing attribute. I just want that notification always stays there. Also, are you suggesting me to use a foreground service?

Comment: How is it irrelevant to `onGoing` attribute then? I don't understand your logic. An ongoing notification will be dismissed automatically(by the android device as you say) when an app is closed irrespective of whatever you are trying. You have used the attribute in your code.

Comment: Yes, you can use a foreground service if `your app needs to perform a task that is noticeable by the user even when they're not directly interacting with the app` as mentioned in the documentation.

Comment: You are saying the same thing. Whether the onGoing attribute is true or not, the notification will be dismissed. So the problem must be in somewhere else. And also, I'll try your suggestion and write down the result. Thanks ^^